# How do I do null check simply on angular map function?

Tags: angular

How do I do null check before map function simply on this sample different from if-else block?

```
this.model.EmployeeStaff = this.form.value.EmployeeStaff.map(p => new EmployeeStaffAddModel(p.Staff.Id, p.StartDate, p.EndDate));
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to apply the null check on? `p` ? or `p.Staff`?

Comment: @SiddAjmera this.form.value.EmployeeStaff before map function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `&&` operator which the code eventually boils down to after minification.

Try this:

```
this.model.EmployeeStaff = this.form.value &&
  this.form.value.EmployeeStaff && 
  this.form.value.EmployeeStaff.map(
    p => new EmployeeStaffAddModel(p.Staff.Id, p.StartDate, p.EndDate)
  );
```

Also, [**Angular recommends using Interfaces**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) instead of Classes for Data Model.

> Consider using an interface for data models.